# solving XOR with single layer perceptron

Tags: neural-network, xor, perceptron

I've always heard that the XOR problem can not be solved by a single layer perceptron (not using a hidden layer) since it is not linearly separable. I understand that there is no linear function that can separate the classes.

However, what if we use a non-monotonic activation function like sin() or cos() is this still the case? I would imagine these types of functions might be able to separate them.

Answer (score 7):

**Yes**, a single layer neural network with a non-monotonic activation function **can** solve the XOR problem. More specifically, a periodic function would cut the XY plane more than once. Even an [Abs](http://hsmazumdar.net/single_layer_neural_net.htm) or [Gaussian](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.38.9055&rep=rep1&type=pdf) activation function will cut it twice.

Try it yourself: W1 = W2 = 100, Wb = -100, activation = exp(-(Wx)^2)

- exp(-(100 * 0 + 100 * 0 - 100 * 1)^2) = ~0
- exp(-(100 * 0 + 100 * 1 - 100 * 1)^2) = 1
- exp(-(100 * 1 + 100 * 0 - 100 * 1)^2) = 1
- exp(-(100 * 1 + 100 * 1 - 100 * 1)^2) = ~0

Or with the abs activation: W1 = -1, W2 = 1, Wb = 0 (yes, you can solve it even without a bias)

- abs(-1 * 0 + 1 * 0) = 0
- abs(-1 * 0 + 1 * 1) = 1
- abs(-1 * 1 + 1 * 0) = 1
- abs(-1 * 1 + 1 * 1) = 0

Or with sine: W1 = W2 = -PI/2, Wb = -PI

- sin(-PI/2 * 0 - PI/2 * 0 - PI * 1) = 0
- sin(-PI/2 * 0 - PI/2 * 1 - PI * 1) = 1
- sin(-PI/2 * 1 - PI/2 * 0 - PI * 1) = 1
- sin(-PI/2 * 1 - PI/2 * 1 - PI * 1) = 0

Answer (score 4):

## No, not without "hacks"

The reason why we need a hidden layer is intuitively apparent when illustrating the xor problem graphically.

[image]

You cannot draw a single sine or cosine function to separate the two colors. You need an additional line (hidden layer) as depicted in the following figure:

[image]

Comment: But lets suppose a non monotonic function exists that locally looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/Qi1FM3n.png
This would surely separate the classes right? Could we not rotate / transform the sin/cos functions to get the same behaviour?

Comment: A function cannot map to two different x values. If the graph maps eg: x=0 -> y = 0.8 and y = -0.8 (as in the image you posted), it cannot be described by a regular function. This prevents us from using any methods requiring a derivate of the activation function.

Comment: I don't quite understand why this is the case in a (single layer) perceptron. We can simply update the weights using the difference between the desired output and and output calculated right?

Comment: I think that the transforming into a new feature space after linear transformation(which obviously should have well-selected coefficients) can change position of data in 2D-space. And that can be divided by non-monotonic function.

Answer (score 0):

In a recent paper, the authors designed a neuron they called [Growing Cosine Unit(GCU)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2108.12943.pdf):

[image]