# Perceptron : Weight for each sample data , or one common weight

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, perceptron

With Perception learning, I am really confused on initializing and updating weight. If I have a sample data that contains 2 inputs x0 and x1 and I have 80 rows of these 2 inputs, hence 80x2 matrix.

Do I need to initialize weight as a matrix of 80x2 or just 2 values w0 and w1 ? Is final goal of perceptron learning is to find 2 weights w0 and w1 which should fit for all 80 input sample rows ?

I have following code and my errors never get to 0, despite going up to 10,000 iterations.

```
x=input matrix of 80x2
y=output matrix of 80x1
n = number of iterations
w=[0.1,0.1]  
learningRate = 0.1
for i in range(n): 
    expectedT = y.transpose();
    xT = x.transpose()
    prediction =  np.dot (w,xT) 

    for i in range (len(x)):    
        if prediction[i] >= 0:                               
                 ypred[i] = 1                               
        else:                                   
                ypred[i] = 0

    error = expectedT - ypred

    # updating the weights
    w = np.add(w,learningRate*(np.dot(error,x)))
    globalError = globalError + np.square(error)
```

Comment: You have 80 samples with 2 features. For each feature you will train one weight if you use a single layer perceptron. Hence you will need only 2 weights. But it's also common to introduce a bias layer with another weight. Thus you would use 3 weights. Also It is possible that your error will never reach 0 as a single layer perceptron can not solve xor for example.

Comment: @mjspier Thank you for confirming on weight. In code I shared, once in an iteration if there is no error, do I need to ignore that sample row in next iteration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each feature you will have one weight. Thus you have two features and two weights. It also helps to introduce a bias which adds another weight. For more information about bias check this [Role of Bias in Neural Networks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480650/role-of-bias-in-neural-networks). The weights indeed should learn how to fit the sample data best. Depending on the data this can mean that you will never reach error of 0. For example a single layer perceptron can not learn an XOR gate when using a monotonic activation function. ([solving XOR with single layer perceptron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30412427/solving-xor-with-single-layer-perceptron)).

For your example I would recommend two things. Introducing a bias and stopping the training when the error is below a certain threshold or if error is 0 for example.

I completed your example to learn a logical AND gate:

```
# AND input and output
x = np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]])
y = np.array([0,1,1,1])

n = 1000
w=[0.1,0.1,0.1]  
learningRate = 0.01
globalError = 0

def predict(X):
    prediction =  np.dot(w[0:2],X) + w[2] 
    ypred = np.zeros(len(y))
    for i in range (len(y)):    
        if prediction[i] >= 0:                               
                ypred[i] = 1                               
        else:                                   
                ypred[i] = 0
    return ypred

for i in range(n): 
    expectedT = y.transpose();
    xT = x.transpose()
    ypred = predict(xT)

    error = expectedT - ypred
    if sum(error) == 0:
        break

    # updating the weights
    w[0:2] = np.add(w[0:2],learningRate*(np.dot(error,x)))
    w[2] += learningRate*sum(error)
    globalError = globalError + np.square(error)
```

After the training the error is 0

```
print(error)
# [0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

And the weights are as follows

```
print(w)
#[0.1, 0.1, -0.00999999999999999]
```

The perceptron can be used now as AND gate:

```
predict(x.transpose())
#array([0., 1., 1., 1.])
```

Hope that helps